# Not getting json response on first click using alamofire

Tags: json, swift3, alamofire

I am using alamofire for getting JSON response.
When I click on the button for the first time, I am not getting response. I've checked after few times just to be sure that whether my internet speed is low. Internet speed is okay and still every time this happens, not entering in the if condition to print the response. Please help. Thanks in advance.!!

Below is my code

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

                if let JSON = response.result.value
                {
                    let responseRes = JSON as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    print("Response = \(responseRes!)")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Will please Try:- let responseRes = JSON["data"]! as! Array<Any>

Answer (score 0):

This will perfectly work in **Swift 3.1**

```
func testURL () {
    let parameter = ["id": 19, "name": "", "image_name": "", "largeimage": "", "catdata": ["category_name"]] as [String: Any]
    //Here parameter as per your web service.
    //var parameter = [String : Any]()
    //print("t:-\(parameter)")
    guard let url = URL(string: "YourWebServiceURL") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options: []) else { return }

    request.httpBody = httpBody

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) {(data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)

            do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String: Any]

                print(json["data"]!)
                let dataarray = json["data"]! as! Array<Any>
                for i  in dataarray {
                    let webServiceArray = i as! [String : Any]
                    //Below all the Object as per you webService objects.
                    print(webServiceArray["name"]!)
                    print(webServiceArray["largeimage"]!)
                    print(webServiceArray["image_name"]!)
                    print(webServiceArray["id"]!)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
        .resume()
}
```

Access this function in **ViewDidLoad**.

Comment: I want to do this using alamofire. if possible, give solution with this. thanks

Comment: can you send me the link of your webservice?